# Why is this code outputting multiple of the same prime numbers?

Tags: python, numbers

Hi everyone :) (I am very new at this)

I am playing around with a simple piece of code which should print the prime numbers in a given range.

```py
nums = range(1, 11)

for number in nums:
    if number > 1:
        for i in range(2, number):
            if(number % i) == 0:
                break
            else:
                print(number)
```

The output I get is as follows...

```
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
9
```

I can't understand why it is printing the prime numbers multiple times.

I expected it to print the numbers...

3,5,7,9

But cannot seem to understand why it is printing 5 3 times and 7 5 times etc.

Comment: If you were to change your print to: `print(number, i)` you might start to understand what is happening.

Comment: I thought 9 wasn't a prime number, because it has 3 factors (1, 3, 9)

Comment: Ah you are right. 9 shouldn't be there

Comment: You have a print statement inside a for-loop. Unless you know otherwise, you should expect it might print multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to move the print(number) statement outside of the else block,

```
nums = range(1, 11)

for number in nums:
    if number > 1:
        for i in range(2, number):
            if (number % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(number)
```